# connection to the database, mysql and php. whats the solution to below error

Tags: php

> Fatal error: Uncaught mysqli_sql_exception: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES) in C:\xampp\htdocs\Poultry-farming-management-system-main\pofarms\database\server.php:25 
> Stack trace: 
> #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\Poultry-farming-management-system-main\pofarms\database\server.php(25): mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'pofarms_db') 
> #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\Poultry-farming-management-system-main\pofarms\database\config.php(3): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') 
> #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\Poultry-farming-management-system-main\pofarms\index.php(2): include('C:\xampp\htdocs...') 
> #3 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\Poultry-farming-management-system-main\pofarms\database\server.php on line 25

Comment: getting the error but i have made some changes to my code. how do i solve it

Comment: Well you could start by showing us the code

Comment: But it looks to me like you are using the wrong password for the `root` userid. ___Big Note___ You should not be using the `root` userid in your site code. Create a user account that is allowed only to see this database, its more secure

Comment: This is a server / database issue. You need to precise the environnement you are working in.

Comment: setting the environment how/

Answer (score 1):

`pofarms_db` looks like the database name and not a password.

Try this connection

```
$db = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', 'password_here', 'pofarms_db');
//  User real password here                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

If as is likely the password is actually blank then try

```
$db = new mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'pofarms_db');
```